# Firefox says Server not found on Ubuntu but not in Windows

Tags: networking, 14.04, firefox

I'm newbie to **Ubuntu** and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (dual booted with **Windows 7**). Last few days it was working fine but from today my problem as follow as,

**FIREFOX NOT WORKING IN UBUNTU**

- Note: I had firefox only. Not anymore chrome etc...

Its says only,

```
SERVER NOT FOUND
```

But I don't see any network connecting problem in Windows 7

**Note:**

```
1. using Ethernet.
2. No proxey.
3. Manual method.
4. IPv4 settings.  
5. Wired connection.
```

**update:**

```
ip         -> 198.168.20.93   
netmask    -> 255.255.255.0   
gateway    ->198.168.20.14
dnsserver  ->198.168.20.14
```

How can I resolve my internet issue?

**UPDATE 1:**

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:c0:80:19:d3  
          inet addr:198.168.20.93  Bcast:198.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:c0ff:fe80:19d3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:157600 errors:1865 dropped:2455 overruns:0 frame:1865
          TX packets:6437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12506428 (12.5 MB)  TX bytes:349342 (349.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:897196 (897.1 KB)  TX bytes:897196 (897.1 KB)
```

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         198.168.20.14   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
198.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ ping www.google.com**

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Did you actually enter .xx in the IP address? That would not be a valid address. Then, 255.255.255.0 is not a valid gateway. In this place you should enter the IP address of your router. In this case, the netmask should be 255.255.255.0. Also, when applying the manual network settings, I think you forgot to enter DNS settings. You need to enter the IP address of at least one (preferably two) DNS servers.

Comment: @Jos, thanks for very first replay, Dns Server is add as same as the netmask..

Comment: @Jos, pls check my update details,...

Comment: Hi! Can I please ask for the output of 1. `ifconfig`, 2. `route -n` , 3. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & last 4. `ping google.com`. ** Edit your question and post those information please. Before, that make sure your firefox settings are been set to use **auto detect** on pictures as seen in [**this answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/269618/179042). This is to show you where to find the proxy settings but not doing the same as what mentioned there.

Comment: When you refer to manual method. Are you referring to Firefox connection settings. If so then with no proxy you should have Firefox set to use system or no proxy.

Comment: I see there's something wrong with the DNS. Why is your DNS server says **127.0.1.1** instead the local host which is **127.0.0.1**. How did you add IP's manually? using the GUI or using commands (via terminal)??

Comment: @AzkerM, via terminal only...

Comment: Can I please have the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Do not hide the IP's with **x** as these are private IP's. And the output does not contain any harmful information though.

Comment: @AzkerM, pls check my **update 2:**

Comment: I'm not sure where you exactly updated those manual IP's so to speak. Look at my answer [**here**](http://askubuntu.com/a/484384/179042) where I helped to assign IP's along with DNS. May be this could help or please post again.

Comment: @AzkerM, I'm checking that but same result..

Comment: finally, its connecting. but, still sometimes connecting and sometime not.... any thanks for useful ideas and suggestions..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that these addresses starting with 198 are wrong. Try to enter 192 instead of 198.

Answer (score 0):

switch the values of gateway and netmask (are these the same as in windows?).

```
ip        -> 198.168.20.93
netmask   -> 255.255.255.0 
gateway   -> 198.168.20.01 (router address)
dnsserver -> 198.168.20.01 (router address, also try 8.8.8.8)
```

Have you tried Automatic (DHCP)?

Comment: sorry, its not working same result in DHCP

Answer (score 0):

Finally [user300458](https://askubuntu.com/a/491685/299481) finding right one:

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf**

but  @AzkerM telling some use full and some change with got the solution,

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

**ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet loopback
```

Comment: my bad!! 198 looks like 192 for me.. that got me confusing but still if your router was issuing such serious that would've been... This is why I prefer the exact information without editing is posted. So, we will get a better understanding.